# How to protect globals variables for beeing overridden in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, overriding, global

I would like to know if there is any way to ensure that some variables aren't overridden by mistake in a Node.js program.

Since it is not possible to set a var as `final` like in Java, I don't see any way to ensure the stability of a global that could be overridden from anywhere, even from template files like EJS.

Non-regressive tests, code review, use of packages and so are some *ways* to detect or avoid such mistakes, but I'm wondering if something stronger can be used in Node especially.

Comment: You could store your variables as key/value pairs in an object and then `seal` or `freeze` the object depending on your requirements.

Comment: A really interesting document, see the part *sealing objects, freezing them and preventing extensibility*: http://bjorn.tipling.com/advanced-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can create objects that are non-writable or frozen

```
var obj = {
    test : 'test'
}

Object.freeze(obj);

obj.test = 'something else';

console.log(obj.test); // still "test"
```

As far as I know there's no way to lock a variable, just properties of objects

Comment: Hum, I see. But is it a working solution to store libraries? Like mongoose, _, lodash, that kind of stuff. I'm wondering if freezing a whole library wouldn't lead to mistakes during the execution. Ah, ok... I'd need to "lock" a whole variable, meaning not overriding it but allow it to change its own sub variables in the case of a library for instance..

Comment: If you have to lock variables containing entire libraries, you're doing something wrong, there shouldn't be any need to do anything like that.

Comment: freeze will freeze the properties.. it will not be variable anymore. i.e. cant be changed.. just freezed.. like a constant..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Object.freeze` mentioned by others node.js should also support the `const` keyword, at least when running with es6 enabled.
That's for block-scoped variables though, not for properties.

Alternatively `Object.defineProperty` could be used to define a non-writeable, non-configurable property. That should also work on the module or global objects, although I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: So, `const` could be use in a global context even for libraries, if I understand correctly? It may be the best option so far, I'm still running ES5 but that's not a big issue.

Comment: `const` is like `let`, it doesn't set properties, it just puts them on the local scope chain.

Comment: Okay... So a global *const* isn't possible at all then. But it seems to be possible to set a global constant on the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const, so why not in Node? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: And in my browser (chrome 39) I am able to set constants for objects and functions that aren't overridable and in a global context, I've just tried.

Comment: "So a global const isn't possible at all then." node works with modules, browsers don't have modules, they have one global namespace. This is intentional so that one module doesn't pollute another and they have to explicitly import from each other as needed. As for setting/exporting properties, see the alternative described in my answer.